# JS - Callback is not being asynchronous

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm a JS student - so I'm sorry about this novice question.
I have the code below and that is not running asynchronously.

```js
let var1 = 0
function fn2(){
  setTimeout(()=>{var1 = 3},5000)
}

function fn1(callback){
try{
callback
}catch(error){
  console.log(error)
}
console.log(1+var1)
}

fn1(fn2)
```

I made this way so you guys could understand more easily. IRL - fn2 is an API.

The return here was expected to be  `4`
But is returning `1`

I know this is basic - I'm really sorry about this.
I understand what callback is for - but it's the syntax that I'm not getting.

Edit: Sorry, guys, I think I was not clear enough with my question so I'll add- " Is there any way to make it work? "
Ty sooooo much for the attention.

Comment: change the code in the setTimeout, adding `console.log('setting the value to 3 now');` ... obviously fix the `callback` to `callback()` in the `try` block ... then watch the console, see how the code in the setTimeout is asynchronously called 5 seconds after the `console.log(1+var1)` has finished

Comment: Oh.... actually It's the other way around that I'm expecting. 
I want ``console.log(1+var1)`` to be called AFTER the setTimeout function.

Comment: I know, but your code doesn't do that, that's how asynchrony works

Comment: Ah, okay... I reckoned that. Ty for trying to clarify to me. =)... it really isn't...

Comment: If you want the console.log to happen after the setTimeout, you need to pass a callback to that fn2 to be called in the setTimeout - I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the console.log after the setTimeout, you'd need to add a callback to fn2 to be called in the setTimeout

```js
let var1 = 0

function fn2(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var1 = 3;
    callback();
  }, 5000)
}

function fn1(callback) {
  try {
    callback(() => {
      console.log('asynch', 1 + var1)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log('synch', 1 + var1)
}

fn1(fn2)
```

Alternatively you could use Promises in fn2, and async/await for fn1,
e.g ...

```js
let var1 = 0

function fn2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var1 = 3;
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });
}

async function fn1(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log(1 + var1)
}

fn1(fn2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's hard to understand the instructions from Jaromanda :) Here's a working example. Everything gets easier with practice. Good luck :)

```js
let var1 = 0
function fn2(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('Setting var1 = 3');
    var1 = 3;
    console.log('adding 1 to var1. Result = ', 1 + var1);
    },5000)
}

function fn1(callback){
  try{
    callback()
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log(1 + var1)
}

fn1(fn2)
```

Comment: Oh.... actually It's the other way around that I'm expecting. 
I want ``console.log(1+var1)`` to be called AFTER the setTimeout function.